# Spring Rotation [CSIR December 2016]

Tags: geometry

The pitch of a spring is 5 mm. The diameter of the spring is 1 cm. The spring spins about its axis with a speed of 2 rotations/s. The spring appears to be moving to its axis with a speed of x mm/sec.
Find the x?

Answer (score 1):

When it rotates once, it seems it moves ahead by the amount of **pitch** parallel to axis.

In one second, it rotates $2$ times. Thus in one second it moves ahead by twice the pitch, that is $10 mm$.